# Can I use index in MySQL in this way?

Tags: mysql

The SQL is

```
select xxx from xxx where region in (A , B , C)
```

explain the SQL, and I find the SQL does not use index region, when I change the SQL to

`select xxx from xxx where region in (B , C)`
it can use index

The sum of A and B and C is 2000000+, A is 1000000+

Comment: What's the cardinality of region? If it's 3 then I'm guessing it won't matter if mysql uses index or not in the 1st case.

Comment: You may try `select xxx from xxx where region=A UNION ALL select xxx from xxx where region=B UNION ALL select xxx from xxx where region=C`. But I doubt that you'll receive some profit.

Comment: How many rows are in the table? If it's close to the 2,000,000 which match the database will conclude using an index will be slower.